# Reverse NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, macos, nsmutablearray

What is the best/correct way to reverse an NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
themutablearray=[[[themutablearray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: **-1** : Isn't `[[theMutableArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]` should be `[[[theMutableArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] mutableCopy]`

Answer (score 32):

```
theMutableArray=[[[theMutableArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is the **swift** version of **Reverse NSMutableArray**

```
mutablearray =  NSMutableArray(array: YourMutablearray.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
```

In pure Swift, you can use `reverse()`

```
let array = ["Apples", "Peaches", "Plums"]

for item in array.reverse() {
     print("Found \(item)")
}
```

**Source:** [hacking with swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/arrays/how-to-loop-through-an-array-in-reverse)

------ OR  ------

```
var a = [String]()

a.append("1")
a.append("2")
a.append("3")

print(Array(a.reverse())) // In swift 3.0, method is `reversed()`
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not pure swift with the NSObject usage.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3

```
let reversedArray = NSArray()

reversedArray =  NSMutableArray(array:TableDataArr.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
```

Answer (score 0):

you can reverse nsmutablearray with the help of reverseObjectEnumerator.
It will return you nsarray then you should create a nsmutablearray with the help of this nsarray

```
NSArray* reversedArray = [[TableDataArr reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
TableDataArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:reversedArray];
```

Comment: No need for the second line, use mutableCopy: NSMutableArray* reversedArray = [[[TableDataArr reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] mutableCopy];

Answer (score 0):

Why all the complication?  Use this:

Swift 3:

```
let tasksArray = NSArray() 
var reversedTaskArray = tasksArray.reversed() as NSArray
```

Answer (score 0):

NSArray *Farr = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7"];

```
NSMutableArray *Reversearr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSInteger j=[Farr count];
for (int i=1; i<=j; i++) {
    [Reversearr1 addObject:[Farr objectAtIndex:j-i] ];
}
```